# jQuery - jqGrid - formatting in loadcomplete event - Firefox, IE & Chrome

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, jqgrid, header

I have the following code in the loadComplete event of a jqGrid.

```
loadComplete: function() { 
    $("td",".jqgrow").height(40);
     // alternate background of every other row
    $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css({"background-color": "#DDDDDC", "background-image": "none"});
    $("th.ui-th-column").css({"font":"bold"});
    }
```

In each browser, the first two lines (height & odd row background) work.  However, the third line ( `$(th.ui-th-column).css({"font":"bold"});` ) only works in IE.

In Firefox, each of the column headers has a class of:

`class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr"` and a `role="columnheader"`.

same thing in IE8.

If I wrap the HTML inside jqGrid's `colNames` - it works in each browser.  What I am wanting to do is to **bold** the font for each column header.  Not sure why the `loadComplete` seems to only apply 2 of the 3 outside of IE.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 $("th.ui-th-column").css({"font":"bold"});
```

Try this

```
 $("th.ui-th-column").css("font","bold");
```

Comment: The above works in IE8, but has no effect in Firefox or Chrome.  On each of the th rows in IE, they have a `style="width:xxxpx; font-weight: bold;"` - in Firefox, they only have the `style="width:xxxpx;"` in them.

Comment: I changed the word `"font"` to `"font-weight"` and it works in each browser.